# Why is Windows Azure storage blob XML truncated?

Tags: c#, xml, azure-storage

I'm trying to save an xml file into a blob. I have no error, everything seems fine except when I navigate to the blob url I see a blank page. If I look at the source code of the web page I can see my xml but truncated.
Here is te code.

```
StringBuilder fileString = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings=new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false)
};
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileString, xmlSettings))
{
    bla bla
}
CloudBlockBlob fileBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("site.xml");
fileBlob.UploadText(fileString.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you post the `bla bla`?

Comment: Have you validated that the contents of `fileString` is correct before upload? Have you determined where it gets truncated? (Is it always at the same place?)

Comment: bla bla is very long but I used to create a file that I save on a server so the bla bla creates a correct xml. And when I break on the UploadText line, fileString is not truncated and well formed (I can copy paste it into a txt file, save as xml and open it fine). I'll check if the truncation is always at the same place and revert. I'll even try a smaller string to see and come back to you.

Comment: I made it work and edited my post :-) Tks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in some other post (not so much the problem although it has to do with encoding of text always being utf-16 despite setting up the writer as utf-8). I am now using a Stream and it works fine.

```
MemoryStream fileString = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings=new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Indent = true
};
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileString, xmlSettings))
{
    bla bla
}
CloudBlockBlob fileBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("site.xml");
fileBlob.UploadText(StreamToString(fileString));

private static string StreamToString(Stream stream)
{
    stream.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided to use a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), you can also upload it using [UploadFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717380%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) instead of [UploadText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.uploadtext%28v=azure.10%29.aspx), which encodes the string into a sequence of bytes, creates a memory stream, and calls [UploadFromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj717380%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) anyway.